# Pasar fecha y hora formato JSON PHP a Java

Tags: android, json

Tengo este `JSON` que viene de un `PHP`:

```
[{"id":101,"date":{"timezone":{"name":"Europe\/Berlin","location": {"country_code":"DE","latitude":52.5,"longitude":13.36666,"comments":"most locations"}},"offset":7200,"timestamp":1471212000},
```

¿Cómo puedo pasar esta fecha en formato `JSON` a una fecha de Java? Extraer los campos lo sé hacer, lo que no sé es como usarlos.

Y si es una hora:

```
"time":{"timezone":{"name":"Europe\/Berlin","location":{"country_code":"DE","latitude":52.5,"longitude":13.36666,"comments":"most locations"}},"offset":3600,"timestamp":36000}
```

En este último caso la fecha me da lo mismo, lo importante es pasar la hora a Java.

Luego que obtengo la fecha en Java, ¿qué puedo hacer para mostrar sólo la fecha en un `TextView`? ¿Y mostrar sólo la hora en un `TextView`?

Comment: te refieres a convertir esta fecha en milisegundos a  una "fecha de Java"? Si es así que formato de "fecha de java" deseas?

Comment: Si tienes el valor del campo `"timestamp"` entonces solo debes utilizar `new Date(<valor del campo timestamp>);` para obtener la fecha. Te recomendaría que sería mejor que utilices un formato particular para la fecha en lugar de enviar su valor en milisegundos.

Comment: Gracias a tod@s por vuestras respuestas, estoy intentando asimilarlo y comprender lo que decís. Luiggi Mendoza, desde el lado del servidor, podría enviar lo que quiera en un paquete JSON, como tratarías este problema en lugar de enviar los milisegundos. Por cierto, envío los milisegundos porque lo hace por defecto la clase Serializer del framework que estoy usando, pero podría, como ya digo, construir un json a mano con los campos que desee y ser esto lo que se devuelva a la aplicación android.

Comment: @Red el valor puede venir en milisegundos ya sea la hora o la fecha, ve mi respuesta. Si tienes problema para obtener el valor de timestamp dentro de tu json trata de agregar todo el .json por favor.

Comment: @Red para enviar fechas y que sea soportado en cualquier plataforma, lo mejor es utilizar el estándar [ISO 8601](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/iso8601.htm) que se traduce en los formatos explicados en [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 3):

Para mostrar la fecha en un TextView, si tienes la fecha en una variable tipo String o Date, puedes agregarla de esta forma:

Suponiendo un TextView dentro de nuestro layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Se obtiene la referencia y se agrega el texto:

```
//A partir del id del TextView.
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
//Agregas el texto, el cual puede ser una variable Date o String.
textView.setText(mifecha);
```

Con respecto a cambiar el formato, el formato tu lo puedes decidir, por ejemplo si deseas un formato "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss":

```
//Seguramente obtendras un string del valor de timestamp, hay que convertirlo a long.
String miJSONTimeStamp = "1471212000";
Long miTimeStamp = Long.parseLong(miJSONTimeStamp);    

//Define formato de salida deseado.
String formatoDeseado = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(formatoDeseado);

//Crea objeto para convertir millisegundos a fecha.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(miTimeStamp);

//aplica formato
String fechaconFormat  = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());

//agrega texto con formato dentro del textView.
textView.setText(fechaconFormat);
```

Se tendrá como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si deseas únicamente la fecha simplemente definela dentro del [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
 String formatoDeseado = "yyyy-MM-dd";
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(formatoDeseado);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si deseas únicamente la hora también definela dentro del [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
 String formatoDeseado = "HH:mm:ss";
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(formatoDeseado);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa que formato deseas:

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Tu respuesta es buena, pero no explica cómo obtener la fecha desde el JSON en Java :\

Comment: ohhh pense que ya había obtenido la fecha en millisegundos!, ahora completo mi respuesta con como obtener la fecha desde el .json gracias!

Comment: dice en la pregunta: "xtraer los campos lo sé hacer, lo que no sé es como usarlos."

Comment: También dice: *En este último caso la fecha me da lo mismo, lo importante es pasar la hora a Java*. Creo yo que la respuesta consiste de: asumiendo que se tiene el valor de la fecha/hora en una variable en el cliente (Java), 1) Convertirlo a un objeto `Date`, 2) Utilizar `SimpleDateFormat` para convertir esa fecha/hora en cadena, 3) Mostrar la cadena en un `TextView` (o donde fuese). Esto lo digo porque la fecha no viene en un formato particular sino como milisegundos (lo cual a mi parecer no es bueno).

Comment: tengo una duda no tienes que multiplicar te dejo este link Saludos, p.d: borrare este mensaje jaja me olvide del link http://ideone.com/IyKbBx

Comment: el codigo tiene algunos comentarios para explicar lo que digo y el link para comprobar esta en mi pregunta el primero porque en ideone acabo de ver que no se puso bien Saludos

Comment: *The Unix epoch (or Unix time or POSIX time or Unix timestamp) is the number of seconds....* 1471212000 seconds -> *1000L -> setTimeInMillis, espero entienda lo que le quiero decir, si no le aplicas 1000 setTimeInMillis tratara el dato de igual manera y al no tener 1000 pues la fechas es diferente. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

> Advertencia: Veo que se han borrado los comentarios, si llega a esta
>   pregunta para aplicarlo a Android esta no es su respuesta pues la
>   pregunta original a mutado.

En este link puede ver algunos datos para hacer comprobaciones ect .
http://www.epochconverter.com/timezones?q=1471212000&tz=America%2FNew_York

---

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {


   Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp(1471212000);
   Date date_f = new Date(stamp.getTime() * 1000L);

        System.out.println(date_f.toString());
        System.out.println(date_f);
}
```

El metodo `toString` se aplica zona horaria predeterminada de la JVM, para java.util.Data este no tiene tiempo para la zona.

---

Con `java.time` usted puede manejar el tiempo de varias maneras:

- [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html)
- aplicando un *Offset* [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) - [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html)
- aplicando *ZoneId* [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) - [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)

.

```
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.Instant;

import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {

    Instant instant                  = Instant.now();
    ZoneOffset zone_offset           = ZoneOffset.of( "+01:00" );
    OffsetDateTime offeset_date_time = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zone_offset );       

    System.out.println(instant.toString());
    System.out.println(offeset_date_time.toString());

    ZoneId zone_id = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ); // <- Mirar shortIds link
    ZonedDateTime zoned_date_time = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zone_id );

    System.out.println(zoned_date_time.toString());

    //Formato ejemplo

    DateTimeFormatter formatterOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME; // <-- Mirar link DateTimeFormatter predefined
    String output = formatterOutput.format(zoned_date_time);
}
```

[shortdIds Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#SHORT_IDS)

[DateTimeFormatter predefined Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#predefined)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

---

**Update:**

Ya habia comentado que esto podria ocurrir, en un comentario en la respuesta de Elenasys, pero se lo vuelvo a poner como update (a raiz de su nueva pregunta que por cierto de deje un comentario, explicando como actualizar su pregunta).

> El resultado es: date = 1144015200 time = 36000 14-01-1970 24:0:36

**The Unix epoch (or Unix time or POSIX time or Unix timestamp) is the number of seconds....** 1471212000 seconds -> *1000L -> `setTimeInMillis`, espero entienda lo que le quiero decir, si no le aplicas 1000 a `setTimeInMillis` tratara el dato de igual manera y al no tener 1000 pues la fechas es diferente.

trate lo siguiente, en los lugares dondes usa `setTimeInMillis(dateTimestamp)`:

```
.setTimeInMillis(dateTimestamp * 1000L);
```

Comment: todo los vinculos son en ingles

Comment: @rnd *todos los vinculos son en ingles* ya es la documentacion de Oracle, no veo nada malo en ello. Saludos

Comment: Bueno, pero es un sitio en español. Deberías traducir o explicar en español las partes fundamentales de la respuesta. De lo contrario es inútil a menos que sepas inglés.

Comment: y sobre los link pues no se me parace que es mejor cuando se usan muchas clases en un codigo enlazar con la documentacion, pero eso tambien es depende de cada uno y de las ganas que tenga o crea que es oportuno.

Comment: Me parece importante esta info, el offset e incluso el locale para definir formatos como "d 'de' MMMM 'del' yyyy" usando un locale adecuado, como : new Locale("es", "ES")

Answer (score 0):

Bueno pues ya lo tengo implementado pero falla:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String json = "[{'date':{'timestamp':1144015200}, 'time':{'timestamp':36000}}]";
    long dateTimestamp = 0;
    long timeTimestamp = 0;


    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

        JSONObject jsonObjectDate = jsonObject.getJSONObject("date");
        JSONObject jsonObjectTime =  jsonObject.getJSONObject("time");

        dateTimestamp = Long.parseLong(jsonObjectDate.getString("timestamp"));
        timeTimestamp = Long.parseLong(jsonObjectTime.getString("timestamp"));

        Log.i("Resultado", "date = " + dateTimestamp);
        Log.i("Resultado", "time = " + timeTimestamp);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String fechaTimestamp = String.valueOf(dateTimestamp);
    String formatoFecha = "d-MM-yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(formatoFecha);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(dateTimestamp);

    String fechaConFormato = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
    Log.i("Resultado", fechaConFormato);

    String formatoHora = "k:m:s";
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(formatoHora);

    calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeTimestamp);

    String horaConFormato = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
    Log.i("Resultado", horaConFormato);
}
```

}

El resultado es:
date = 1144015200
time = 36000
14-01-1970
24:0:36

La fecha que tendría que salir es: 03-04-2006 y la hora 11:00:00.

¿Se os ocurre algo? Los timestamp los genera el servidor, no sé si podría estar generándolos mal. Otra opción sería mandar un paquete json con la fecha y hora como String, pero entonces como podría encapsularlo en un objeto fecha de Java.

He hecho esta prueba:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String strFecha = "03-04-2006";
    Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    Date fecha = calendar.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat formatoDeFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Log.i("resultado", formatoDeFecha.format(fecha));
}
```

}

Pero el resultado es: 01/05/2016.

Estoy un poco perdido con esto :(

Gracias por cualquier ayuda que me podáis echar.

Un saludo

Comment: Para añadir mas información a su pregunta, puede ver bajo su pregunta compartir, editar, cerrar, reportar, pudiendo acceder a editar presionado sobre el, y modificando su pregunta, puede copiar el contenido de su respuesta, y pegarlo dentro de su pregunta, después puede eliminar esta respuesta. Saludos